# How can I fix : tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str error

Tags: python

I don't know how I can fix this error

> session['id'] = account['id']
> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
@app.route('/login', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
        msg = ''
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
            username = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']
            
            mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND password = %s", (username, password))
     
            account = mycursor.fetchone()
            if account:
                session['loggedin'] = True
                session['id'] = account['id']
                session['username'] = account['username']
                msg = 'Logged in successfully !'
                return render_template('index.html', msg = msg)
            else:
                msg = 'Incorrect username / password !'
        return render_template('login.html', msg = msg)
```

Comment: `account` is a tuple, not a `dict`. You have to know ahead of time that, say, `account[0]` is the `id` column, etc.

Comment: Consult the documentation for your SQL library to see how, if possible, to get back a `dict` rather than a `tuple`.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by setting account [0] for id and account [1] for username